# Long task, Composite Layers and load img

Tags: javascript, image, browser

The problem is the animation micro-lag when new images are loaded. The size of the images is no more than 1 mb.
The entire image is moved using smooth transform animation.

Tell me why this problem arises and how can it be solved?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXmlA.png)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame Not sure if this will help but when animating there's a natural frame update in browsers they comply to when in focus.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.